# how to find a solution for this problem.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[ (a/b)*c] mod n=k. If b,c,n,k values are known how can I get back a value provided the range of a,b is -(n-1) to n-1 and c is 0 to n-1 where n is a prime number.?

Comment: Isn't the value you're looking for $\equiv k \bmod n$?

Comment: not exactly.. i am looking for how modular reduction is performed when a number is multiplied and divided by some digits..

Comment: yes b is coprime to n

Comment: You can compute it as $\,acb^{-1}$ where $b^{-1}$ can be computed efficiently by the Extended Euclidean algorithm (or closely related methods).